# Please explain the working of repaint() method in java?

Tags: java, awt, repaint

I have seen many questions similar to this But I am not able to understand why the repaint do not work properly

In my program Before exiting the Frame I called repaint() use Thread.sleep to delay the exit then also the msg "Mouse Exited" does not get displayed.

**Can you please explain why this happens or provide the link for the same**

```
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me)
            {
                msg="Mouse Exited";
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

Complete Program

```
/**Write a program to create a frame using AWT. Implement mouseClicked( ),
mouseEntered( ) and mouseExited( ) events. Frame should become visible when
mouse enters it. */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;




class Question8 extends Frame{

           static Dimension original;
           String msg;

         Question8(String s)
        {
           msg=s;
           addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
           {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
            {
                
                msg="Mouse Clicked";
                setSize(original);
                repaint();

                
            }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me)
            {
                msg="Mouse Entered";
                setSize(original.height*3,original.width*3);
                repaint();

            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me)
            {
                msg="Mouse Exited";
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }

            });

            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
            {
                public void windowClosing(Window ev)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            });
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawString(msg, 50, 50);
        }

        public static void main(String agrs[])
        {
            Question8 obj=new Question8("Hello");
            original=new Dimension(300,300);
            obj.setSize(original);
            obj.setTitle("Question 8");
            obj.setVisible(true);
        }

    
}
```

Comment: In your `mouseExited()` method you add a repaint request via `repaint()`. This would be considered, however there is one issue. You are blocking the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) which is responsible for the repainting to be done. The EDT enters your `mouseExited()` method, gets told to repaint in the near future, is then blocked by your `Thread.sleep(1000)` for one second (in this time it can't do anything, since it sleeps), then you exit your application via `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: Once you remove the `Thread.sleep()` and the `System.exit()` from your `mouseExited()`, you should at least be able to see something. However, you should consider the comments from your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356177/when-is-the-repaint-method-called.

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. Note that Swing also provides a `Timer` that is well suited to this use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As maloomeister pointed out, the `Thread.sleep()` is blocking the event thread, so you need to create a new thread.

If you replace your `mouseExited` method with this it will behave as you expect:

```
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
                msg = "Mouse Exited";
                repaint();
                new Thread(() -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.exit(0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                ).start();
            }
```